# users api of geoserver

Tags: api, geoserver

I was using geoserver api to create a new user for my application, after I upgraded my geoserver to 2.18.2 the same code doesn't work any more.
until now I used this route which was working absolutely fine:

```
http://geoserver:8080/geoserver/geofence/rest/usergroup/service/jdbc_userservice/users
```

If i still use this route, I get this error:

```
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Therefore I tried this route which I found in their api docs:

```
localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users
```

but I get this error:

```
Type Status Report

Message Forbidden

Description The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
```

any hint or docs about this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: did you upgrade the geofence plugin to match the new version?

Comment: thanks a lot, no I didn't, I will give it a try